# "Failed to create temp file 18" error on published github page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I have created a simple application using Create-React-App (CRA). The problem is that even though the app runs perfectly fine on my localhost (ie, after using `npm start`), when I try to publish my pages to gh-pages (`npm run build`, and `npm run deploy`), I am not able to load the page using the URL. I don't even see any errors in console at first, but after a while (or more specifically, after I open the Timeline tab in console), I see the following error.

> Failed to create temp file 18 : It was determined that certain files
>   are unsafe for access within a Web application, or that too many calls
>   are being made on file resources.

I do see this warning on my local dev environment,

> [Violation] Long running JavaScript task took 229ms

and the minified bundle.js file goes to about 4MB in size. But I guess this is not the issue because my other projects have the same warning and they are published just fine.

I'm also fairly confident that this is a more JavaScript related issue, rather than CRA related. I read somewhere that this might be a network mapping of resources issue. But so far, I'm not really sure what this means or how to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

Just to answer my own question, in case anybody else lands up here.

The issue was in the way I was using `react-router`. I was initially using `browserHistory` instead of `hashHistory`.

As per the docs,

> GitHub Pages doesn’t support routers that use the HTML5 pushState
>   history API under the hood (for example, React Router using
>   browserHistory). This is because when there is a fresh page load for a
>   url like http://user.github.io/todomvc/todos/42, where /todos/42 is a
>   frontend route, the GitHub Pages server returns 404 because it knows
>   nothing of /todos/42.

More information can be [found here](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#step-5-optionally-configure-the-domain).